# OnValidateIdentity session is null - Mvc Owin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, identity, asp.net-identity, owin

Currently, I have problems when access Session in OnValidateIdentity - `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null. What's wrong? My application as below:

- I have 2 project : Mvc vs WebApi

I want user will logout when I changed password -> change security stamp.
I implement as: The Mvc Project will validate SecurityStamp changed when user request. And I'm will get SecurityStamp from other webapi website . This mean My mvc not access directly to database that through out webapi. And I'm must be input token in authorize header to get securitystamp from webapi. But, I can't access token from session , when I login successfully I stored the token in the Session. Code example:

```
public void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {            
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Home"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = async ctx =>
                {
                    var claim = ctx.Identity.FindFirst("SecurityStamp");
                    var accessToken = HttpContext.Current.Session["token"].ToString();

                    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        // Used accessToken variable for httpClient
                        // TODO Get security stamp from webapi . Ex :
                        string securityStampWebApi = "demo";
                        if (securityStampWebApi != claim.Value)
                        {
                            ctx.RejectIdentity();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    }
```

suggestion other implementaion to I can finish this case.

Comment: any alternative solutions without use ***Session*** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cookie middleware runs at the authenticate stage in the IIS pipeline, which is prior to `HttpContext`or session state being made available. So you will need to work without it.

Comment: In ***OnResponseSignIn*** `HttpContext.Current` is *not null*, but `HttpContext.Current.Session` is *Null*. Code: `Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
                                {
                                    OnResponseSignIn`

Comment: Which are all ***stages*** in the _IIS pipeline_, using OWIN middleware ?

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `HttpContext.Current` in OWIN callbacks in general, that is most likely the issue.  You should flow in the context provided to the callback.