# HttpContext.Current.Session is null asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, session, session-state

I've got a problem with HttpContext.Current.Session.
I try to enable session state on my application.
I did a few things:

1. add to my web.config:

> ```
> <sessionState 
>    cookieless="UseCookies"
>    regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
>    mode="InProc"
>    timeout="20"/>
> ```

I want to use cookies too so I set up cookieless="UseCookies".

After that I added:

> ```
> <pages enableSessionState="true">
> ```

this page section isn't closed because contains a few namespaces like that:

> ```
> <pages enableSessionState="true">
>  <namespaces>
>    <add namespace="..."/>
>  </namespaces>
> </pages>
> ```

2. In my Global.asax.vb I created two event handlers:

> ```
> Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
>     ' Fires when the session is started
> End Sub
> ```

and

> ```
>  Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
>     ' Fires when the session ends 
>  End Sub
> ```

3. I created some c# class which will be management my session:

> ```
>  public class MySession
>  {
>     public static void Add(string key, object value)
>     {
>         if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null && (HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys == null || (HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys != null && HttpContext.Current.Session[key] == null)))
>         {
>             HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(key, value);
>         }
>     }
>
>     public static void Remove(string key)
>     {
>         ...
>     }
>
>     public static void Update(string key, object value)
>     {
>         ...
>     }
>
>     public static object GetValue(string key)
>     {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

It's all what I did in code and yeah - my app using vb and c# too.
So when I try to use MySession.Add(someKey, someValue) always I've got a HttpContext.Current.Session == null.

It's my first time when I try turn on a session in app so I need help with this.
I was looking for any solution into google but they either didn't work or they were not for me.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you capture the stack trace when the error occurs?

Comment: I haven't any error just first condition of if statement on Add method is false because HttpContext.Current.Session == null. I thought that if I turn on session state in web.config and put enableSesionState in pages section - the session will be automatic created.

Comment: In Session_Start event have you checked `HttpContext.Current.Session != null` is true or false?

Comment: ok I found something. When I implemented Application_AcquireRequestState event handler. It's void a few times - once Session isn't null nextly is null.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood in Session_Start event HttpContext.Current.Session isn't null

Comment: @Presto if you execute MySession.Add method before `Application_PostAcquireRequestState` application event the Session will be null. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postacquirerequeststate(v=vs.110).aspx
So normally we write code for accessing the Session in Page_Load event which is execute in the Application lifecycle after PostAcquireRequestState

Comment: @MohsinMehmood hmm, I try to call MySession.Add into Startup.vb after correctly user log in. I try to add information about user during OnResponseSignIn event's fired (from CookieAuthenticationProvider). Have you got any idea what should I to do with that?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I'll try with OnResponseSignedIn event handler. Maybe OnResponseSignIn was to soon voided

Comment: it's the same... still session is null

Comment: If you're calling the methods from somewhere else where HttpContext.Current.Session is available, then you can pass that as a parameter to your `Add` etc. methods.

Comment: I'll try to do something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593719/onvalidateidentity-session-is-null-mvc-owin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer how to solve my problem. 
I have to use something like `Pipeline` (on proper place in code with proper code logic).

More informations are on this on [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816866/8479567) or on [direct link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline)  on Microsoft Docs.